# Why is my A* implementation slower than floodfill?

Tags: python, path-finding, a-star, flood-fill

I have a blank grid of 100, 100 tiles. Start point is (0,0), goal is (99,99). Tiles are 4-way connections.

My floodfill algorithm finds the shortest path in 30ms, but my A* implementation is around 10x slower.

Note: A* is consistently slower (3 - 10x) than my floodfill, no matter what kind of size of grid or layout. Because the floodfill is simple, then I suspect I'm missing some kind of optimisation in the A*.

Here's the function. I use Python's heapq to maintain a f-sorted list. The 'graph' holds all nodes, goals, neighbours and g/f values.

```
import heapq

def solve_astar(graph):

    open_q = []

    heapq.heappush(open_q, (0, graph.start_point))

    while open_q:

        current = heapq.heappop(open_q)[1]

        current.seen = True # Equivalent of being in a closed queue

        for n in current.neighbours:
            if n is graph.end_point:
                n.parent = current
                open_q = [] # Clearing the queue stops the process

            # Ignore if previously seen (ie, in the closed queue)
            if n.seen:
                continue

            # Ignore If n already has a parent and the parent is closer
            if n.parent and n.parent.g <= current.g:
                continue

            # Set the parent, or switch parents if it already has one
            if not n.parent:
                n.parent = current
            elif n.parent.g > current.g:
                remove_from_heap(n, n.f, open_q)
                n.parent = current

            # Set the F score (simple, uses Manhattan)
            set_f(n, n.parent, graph.end_point)

            # Push it to queue, prioritised by F score
            heapq.heappush(open_q, (n.f, n))

def set_f(point, parent, goal):
    point.g += parent.g
    h = get_manhattan(point, goal)
    point.f = point.g + h
```

Comment: Can you show us `remove_from_heap`? That might be your bottleneck.

Comment: @templatetypedef It's `heap.remove((f_value, tile))` - but even when there are no removals, it doesn't run noticeably faster.

Comment: The heap remove operation runs in linear time, which could completely eat up all the efficiency gains you'd get from an intelligent A* search. Are you sure that this isn't your problem?

Comment: @templatetypedef Yes, it is still ~10x slower, even when that function is never called.

Comment: What is your `set_f` function? Perhaps you have a bad heuristic?

Comment: Added `set_f` - it's a basic Manhattan distance

Comment: Did you try using using [cProfile](http://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html)? `python -m cProfile myscript.py` This will at least tell you where your program is spending all its time.

Comment: @mojo Wow, that's very helpful. It looks like it's examining every node - not sure why it would do that. I assume it's the heuristic, but not sure why - it's just a simple Manhattan distance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a tie-breaker issue. On an empty grid, starting at (0,0) and going to (99,99) produces many tiles with the same f-score.

By adding a tiny nudge to the heuristic, tiles that are slightly closer to the destination will get selected first, meaning the goal is reached quicker and fewer tiles need to be checked.

```
def set_f(point, parent, goal):
    point.g += parent.g
    h = get_manhattan(point, goal) * 1.001
    point.f = point.g + h
```

This resulted in around a 100x improvement, making it much faster than floodfill.